# How to aggregate by Month, Week and Day - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I've collection with tickets, I need to get number of tickets sold on Day, Week and Month. Below is the structure

```js
{
    "_id": "9917aed79fcc274bdefgj",
    "ticketId": 100,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-08T08:34:39.697+00:00"
},
{
    "_id": "9917aed79fcc274bdefgj",
    "ticketId": 101,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-07T08:34:39.697+00:00"
},
{
    "_id": "9917aed79fcc274bdefgj",
    "ticketId": 102,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-06T08:34:39.697+00:00"
},
{
    "_id": "9917aed79fcc274bdefgj",
    "ticketId": 103,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-05T08:34:39.697+00:00"
},
{
    "_id": "9917aed79fcc274bdefgj",
    "ticketId": 104,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-04T08:34:39.697+00:00"
},
{
    "_id": "9917aed79fcc274bdefgj",
    "ticketId": 105,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-03T08:34:39.697+00:00"
},
{
    "_id": "9917aed79fcc274bdefgj",
    "ticketId": 106,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-02T08:34:39.697+00:00"
},
{
    "_id": "9917aed79fcc274bdefgj",
    "ticketId": 107,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-01T08:34:39.697+00:00"
}
```

Im new to MongoDB, I tried using project or match to export the day, week or month however Im unsuccessful and hence could not share much of my work. Appreciate any help

Update: 
Expected output when query for 08-Nov
Day: 1 
Week: 1
Month: 8

Explanation of output:
Day: 1 — no. of tickets sold on the given date
Week: 1 — no. of tickets sold on the given week (starts from Monday, only 1 ticket was sold)
Month: 8 — no. of tickets sold on the given month, 8 tickets were sold

Comment: if it is 1 of the month, on month sum, do you want to get the tickets for that one day? Or the tickets for the last 30 days? even if they are in different months?

Comment: need tickets of ONLY current day, current week and current month. Also updated expecetd output

Comment: In Mongo 5.0 you can also use [$dateTrunc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) which is shorter than `{_id: {year: {$year: "$createdAt"}, month: {$month: "$createdAt"}}}`

Comment: any work around for 3.x?

Comment: $facet works with 3.4, i updated the answer for the current date only, the previous answer was for all possible dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- put the date you want in the first set, if you want for the current date keep the `$$NOW` system variable that has the current date
- 4x the same code for year/month/week/day
- here filters before group, to have the same year or month or week or day with the `$$NOW` date which is the current date.

*i used `$isoWeek` for week to start on monday `$week` starts week at sunday, you can change them

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49d1)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"date": "$$NOW"}},
  {"$facet": 
    {"year": 
      [{"$match": 
          {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$year": "$date"}, {"$year": "$createdAt"}]}}},
        {"$group": {"_id": null, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
        {"$unset": ["_id"]}],
      "month": 
      [{"$match": 
          {"$expr": 
            {"$and": 
              [{"$eq": [{"$year": "$date"}, {"$year": "$createdAt"}]},
                {"$eq": [{"$month": "$date"}, {"$month": "$createdAt"}]}]}}},
        {"$group": {"_id": null, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
        {"$unset": ["_id"]}],
      "week": 
      [{"$match": 
         {"$expr": 
           {"$and": 
            [{"$eq": [{"$year": "$date"}, {"$year": "$createdAt"}]},
             {"$eq": [{"$isoWeek": "$date"}, {"$isoWeek": "$createdAt"}]}]}}},
        {"$group": {"_id": null, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
        {"$unset": ["_id"]}],
      "day": 
      [{"$match": 
          {"$expr": 
            {"$and": 
              [{"$eq": [{"$year": "$date"}, {"$year": "$createdAt"}]},
                {"$eq": 
                  [{"$dayOfYear": "$date"}, {"$dayOfYear": "$createdAt"}]}]}}},
        {"$group": {"_id": null, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
        {"$unset": ["_id"]}]}},
  {"$set": 
    {"year": 
      {"$cond": 
        [{"$eq": ["$year", []]}, 0, {"$arrayElemAt": ["$year.count", 0]}]},
      "month": 
      {"$cond": 
        [{"$eq": ["$month", []]}, 0, {"$arrayElemAt": ["$month.count", 0]}]},
      "week": 
      {"$cond": 
      [{"$eq": ["$week", []]}, 0, {"$arrayElemAt": ["$week.count", 0]}]},
      "day": 
      {"$cond": 
        [{"$eq": ["$day", []]}, 0, {"$arrayElemAt": ["$day.count", 0]}]}}}])
```

**Results**
(for "date" 9 November with my data i got)

```
[
  {
    "day": 1,
    "month": 8,
    "week": 1,
    "year": 8
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Test Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N7FQYY0xzwZ)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "createdAtWeek": {
        "$week": "$createdAt"
      },
      "createdAtMonth": {
        "$month": "$createdAt"
      },
      "createdAtDay": {
        "$dayOfMonth": "$createdAt"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        createdAtWeek: "$createdAtWeek",
        createdAtMonth: "$createdAtMonth",
        createdAtDay: "$createdAtDay"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```